Prediction step of the Kalman Filter
I have experimental data of the my system. In order to estimate the 2 state variables of this system, i implement Kalman Filter using the discrete-time based equations given below.



According to equations,  and  should be taken from the previous step. When I apply this exactly, my prediction results are about 2 times higher. However, when I multiply these values by 0.01 and continue the process, my prediction values are almost the same as the experimental data.
Is my approach correct? Or where may the mistake be?

How certain are you that your model is correct, i.e. $F_n$, $H_n$, $Q_n$ and $R_n$?

Yes, model is correct. I have checked the outputs with the experimental data.

Your are first saying that the prediction step results are about 2 times higher. However, later you state that if you multiply by 0.01 it does match the experimental data. So which factor is it? And what value exactly is off? The resulting predicted output?

When i use Pn-1|n-1 and mn-1|n-1 as 0.01Pn-1|n-1 and 0.01mn-1|n-1, i can obtain the best results.

How did you confirm exactly that your model is correct?

Two times higher than what?  Than you think they should be?  Than how some real system behaves?
